# The grammar of てちょうどいい

Tags: grammar, て-form

Same sentence, different question:

> 「あんたなんて甘やかしたらどこまでもツケあがるタチだから、**厳しくされてちょうどいい**のよ。」
>   If I pamper the likes of you, you'll be endlessly spoiled, so ...

The grammar in the clause in bold is confusing me. 厳しく is "strictly", and I believe ちょうどいい is "just right". されて is presumably the passive て form of する.

Is the て form providing the usual role of joining clauses (i.e. 'and' etc) or does the combination of て and ちょうどいい form a single unit like てある, てほしい etc? So, for example, can I always treat verb-てちょうどいい　to mean "doing verb is just right"?

Finally, how should I translate する? The only translation I can make is "Being **treated** strictly is just right", but I can't find any dictionary that says する can mean "to treat".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

厳しくされてちょうどいい is literally "being done strictly is just right." Translating する as "treated" makes sense because you can infer that what is being done is the treatment of the other character, since that's what they were talking about.

> "(Treatment (of you)) being done strictly is just right"

The words in parentheses are implied from context, not an inherent meaning of する.

> So, for example, can I always treat verb-てちょうどいい　to mean "doing verb is just right"?

Yes, unless ちょうどいい is modifying something after it instead, like 「レストランに行ってちょうどいいプチパンケーキセットを食べたよ。」 "I went to a restaurant and ate a mini-pancake set that was just right (in size)."

Comment: Thought it was an okay explanation until I hit the last part.  If a native speaker, such as myself, said 「レストランに行ってちょうどいいプチパンケーキセットを食べたよ。」, 「ちょうどいい」 would refer to the size (and not the taste or quality) of the meal nearly 100% of the time.  Is that what you meant by "just right"?

Comment: Good point, in English it does sound like it is about the taste or quality. No good examples were coming to mind...

Comment: Not worried about the ambiguity. You told me what I needed to know. Thanks.

Comment: Great! I modified the sentence a little to clarify that it means size, just in case.